# How to check a number, Then reduce by minus?

Tags: php

Basically I need to do a `PHP` code that will play `m3u8` file,
With a bit delay (ms).

And help me to solve the situation of buffering every few minutes.

```
 <?php
    $url = "http://mywebsite.com/playlist.m3u8";
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo $url;
Or with `header('Location:...`
```

In the `echo` I get the names of the `.ts` files inside the `m3u8`:

```
http://mywebsite.com/playlist_204.ts
http://mywebsite.com/playlist_205.ts
http://mywebsite.com/playlist_206.ts
```

I need to check what the number,

Example: 208 or 216 or 230

Then do a calculation -5:

```
if...
echo $result;
// result = 203, 211, 225
}else{
//empty for now
}
```

Then I will arrange the code that he will redirect to:

http://mywebsite.com/playlist_'.$result.ts

Comment: You need the numeric value from the .ts urls?

Comment: @Robert The current code already gets the number, I just need each time the code will work to have some sort of calculation (-5)

Comment: You can have the calculation done in the `if` block.

Comment: @ValerianPereira But I do not know how to calculate with if block, That's why I'm asking for help